# Wazuh CIS benchmark checks

Tags: devsecops

Those familiar with the open source tool called Wazuh probably have used the CIS benchmark tests.

I noticed a lot of typos and/or logic issues with the checks performed by Wazuh, in my case for Ubuntu20.04 , but i notice it's the case for other OSes too.

Here's is one very simple example of a typo, causing Wazuh CIS benchmark checks to fail although it shouldn't :
https://github.com/wazuh/wazuh/pull/20199/files

I am trying to edit the rule and fix the way Wazuh performs the checks by editing the ruleset  file, as proposed in the github PR.

As the issue describes, this should fix the problem, however the issue persist when i try. (After restarting Wazuh services, trying with a fresh agent -> fresh scan, etc...)

I did come across info, that it is no longer possible to alter the rules manually, like i do :
https://documentation.wazuh.com/current/user-manual/ruleset/update.html

So, is it really the case ? I cannot modify the rules and fix silly typos like the one mentioned on github  ?

I was considering downgrading just to address this issue, but it just doesn't sound sane, that i cannot tweak the rules, so that Wazuh performs the checks properly .